# how can fix my code its priting <generator object <genexpr> at ...>?

Tags: python

I'm getting an error, I don't know why my functions is returning `generator object <genexpr>`, how can I fix it?

```
import collections

def compute_word_importance(fpath1,fpath2):
    lists = []
    for filepath in (fpath1, fpath2):
        tmp_list = []
        with open(filepath, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as inputfile:
            for line in inputfile:
                tmp_list.append(word.strip() for word in line.split())

            lists.append(tmp_list)

    if lists[0] == lists[1] == 0:
         return None

    counter = collections.Counter(lists[0])
    counter.subtract(lists[1])
    return counter
```

Automatic evaluation

```
Testing if "compute_word_importance()" returns an empty Counter for empty files.
OK: The returned Counter is correct.
Testing if "compute_word_importance()" returns Counter with negative values for empty first file.
ERROR: The returned Counter is not correct:
... Observed: Counter({<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f13de3b6708>: -1, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f13de3b6630>: -1, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f13de3b66c0>: -1, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f13de3b6750>: -1, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f13de3b6678>: -1})
... Expected: Counter({'yybieqgmuhqaqrkrfjtjoegqgxgza': -1, 'lbcqhmlnpvz': -1, 'igr': -1, 'kzjry': -1, 'tuas': -1, 'f': -1, 'twmu': -1, 'zvg': -1, 'l': -1, 'j': -1, 'vqdkprzqc': -1})
```

example. expected output `Counter({'language.': 1, 'Python': 1, 'programming': 1, 'about': 0, 'This': 0, 'is': 0, 'text': 0, 'Spam.': -1})`

Comment: `tmp_list.append(word.strip() for word in line.split())`. You're appending generators to your list.

Comment: Do you want each line to be its own list? Or should all of them be one list?

Comment: all of them in one list as in my example for an expected output just now i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `extend` *not* `append` if you want a flat list of elements which based on the fact you are counting is exactly what you want, extend will also work with a generator expression:

```
tmp_list.extend(word.strip() for word in line.split())
```

If you were to append lists to `tmp_list` then you would be attempting to pass lists of lists to Counter which would not work.